# What is the role of the annotation @EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

I want to understand what is the role of `@EJB` and what the container does during the injection.

I am beginner in Java EE, and for the moment I use the dependencies injection for using EJB because I have learnt with this method.

For example, I have a local interface

```
@Local
public interface MyInterface
```

then, I implement this interface

```
@Stateless
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface
```

and when I want to use the EJB, I write

```
@EJB
MyInterface ejb;
```

Firstly, I don't understand really what happens in the container during the injection dependencies.

Moreover, why is better (or not maybe) to use the interface to call the EJB whereas use the EJB (which in my opinion will be more direct)

```
MyInterfaceImpl ejb;
ejb.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When the container sees your `@EJB` it knows that it should find the correct implementation of the EJB interface, instantiate this bean (reflection version of `new MyInterfaceImpl()`), call its lifecycle methods and then make it available for you.
   It does all that for you - you just focus on the business logic and dependencies and not on the configuration, instantiation or lifecycle management of the dependent EJB.
2. It's possible to inject an EJB implementor class directly (`@LocalBean` -- no-interface view). For some simple cases that's enough and you can be happy with it. Nevertheless, for other real-life examples, you might want to swap the implementation of an EJB business interface in deployment-time. This implementation might differ from deployment to deployment. 
   Hardcoding the implementor class in your code as you've shown makes you tightly coupled to the realization of the interface -- i.e. you're not able to swap it without recompiling the  code.

Comment: Thank you Piotr. If I have an interface and 3 implementations, how can the container know the EJB corresponding ? I suppose by using the parameters of the annotation. But in this case, we need to recompile the code to swap an implementation too, don't we ?

Comment: Yes, you're right in case you use annotations parameters like beanName or beanInterface. But remember that you can do the same in deployment descriptor (`ejb-jar.xml`). This is purely deployment-dependent. Moreover, imagine you have an EAR (or WAR) and you have interface and implementations in different JAR's within it. You can then decide what JARs become a part of your EAR in deployment time -- to make sure only one implementation of EJB interface is in EAR/WAR.